# Visual Studio 2019 is not detecting Windows Mobile Emulator

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2019

Recently switched from Visual Studio 2017 to 2019 and now it's not detecting the installed Windows 10 Mobile emulator version 10.0.10586.11 that I use to debug backwards compatibility. Works fine on VS2017.

I tried reinstalling the emulator, but it's not being listed in my debug options in Visual Studio. This is the only emulator I install/need because the other testing I do on physical devices.

My machine is running Windows 10, version 1809, if that helps.

What can I do to remedy this?

Comment: Is there a reason you believe `Windows 10 Mobile Emulator` is compatible with Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: Hi. Visual Studio 2019 allows development targeting the same version of Windows 10 as this emulator. So it would be very odd if it wasn't compatible.

Comment: You are going to have to help me.  So the `Windows 10 Mobile Emulator` treated as an add-on perhaps by Visual Studio?  Besides it being a debug option how do you know it's working with VS2017?

Comment: Yes, if emulators are installed and the project targets the version as the emulator, it is listed in the debug options, kind of like in the images on [this page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/test-with-the-emulator). They show up in VS2017 but not VS2019 despite having the same project and configurations and all. Other debug options work fine on VS2019.

Comment: Apparently, this is a bug with Visual Studio. I created the issue [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/371505b6-ce94-40a2-9c98-ea46a6d8d2d8/visual-studio-2019-is-not-detecting-windows-mobile-emulator?forum=wpdevelop) and they will check up on it.